# Sitecore publishing targets greyed out in Publish dialog

Tags: security, sitecore

I've an installation of Sitecore 6.5, with 2 publishing targets. 2 users with apparently the same permissions have different behavior in the Content Editor.  They can both open the Publish dialog, but one of the 2 has the publishing targets that are greyed out (all other radio buttons and checkboxes are available).

I've checked the role membership : all the groups are identical (including Content Publishing).
The access viewer gives the same result (for menu items in the core database or for publishing targets in the master database).

The security field on the publishing targets in the content editor are empty.
The flag Publishing.CheckSecurity in the web.config is equal to FALSE.

The user has done a test on different machines (this appears not to be linked with the client), and has checked with different content (media files or pages).

Do you have any idea of what I could still check ?

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: don't forget to mark the correct answer if one of the answers below resolved your issue.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked whether the user's have write access to the publishing target? The dialog iterates over all publishing targets and will do the following check:

```
!obj.Access.CanWrite()
```

If the user cannot write to the publishing target item, the checkbox will be disabled.

I would recommend using the Access Viewer with the user that is having the problem to see why the Write access is being denied for that user to the publishing target item. You mention that the Access Viewer has the same access, but did you check all permissions or just Read?

Comment: This solution applies to most likely any (newer) Sitecore version, the answer helped me with Sitecore 8.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a "`DefaultPublishingTargets`" node in your web.config.  You can specify your publishing targets (pipe-delimited) and that should at least force them to be checked when publishing.